# inverse z-transform of $\frac{1}{(1-z^{-1})^{2}}$

Tags: z-transform

how to find inverse-z-transform of:

$$
x[n] = Z-Transform\left\{ \frac{1}{(1-z^{-1})^{2}} \right\}
$$

I could convert it to convolution... but then i'm stuck with solving convolution...which i'm not really sure how to perform either.

A few z-transform table definitions I'm looking at to solve the problem:

$$
\begin{aligned}
X(z) &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] z^{-n} \\
\\
\alpha^{n}\ u[n] &<=> \frac{1}{1-\alpha z^{-1}} \\
\\
x[n]*y[n] &<=> X(z)\ Y(z) \\
\\
x[n-k] &<=> z^{-k}X(z)
\end{aligned} 
$$

Comment: Use $3,4,5,6$ of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Table_of_common_Z-transform_pairs

Answer (score 1):

for positive m:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c} n + m - 1 \\ m - 1 \end{array} \right)\ a^n\ u[n] <=> \frac{1}{(1-a z^{-1})^m} 
$$

$$
\left(\begin{matrix}n\\k\\\end{matrix}\right)=\frac{n\left(n-1\right)\ldots\left(n-k+1\right)}{k\left(k-1\right)\ldots1}
$$

for m=2:

$$
(n+1)\ a^{n}\ u[n] <=> \frac{1}{(1-az^{-1})^2}\ \ \ \ ROC: |z| > |a|
$$